# Erlang / OTP App's handle_info not getting {nodedown, _, _ } or {nodedown, _} messages

Tags: erlang, distributed, erlang-otp

I have an Erlang/OTP app, whose handle_info function is not getting `{nodedown, _, _ }` or `{nodedown, _ }` messages when a companion node goes down. However, when the companion node comes back up, I do get `{nodeup, _, _}` messages.

I use `net_kernel:monitor_nodes( true, [{node_type, all}])` in the OTP server's `init/1` function.

Also, if I start this OTP app as an application, and `receive X->X` done. on the shell, and then kill the companion node, I do get a `{nodedown, _, _ }` on the shell !

So why isn't handle_info getting the message if the shell is ?

Thanks !

Comment: We probably need some more code to see what is going on. From what you are writing, it should be delivered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'twas an issue with compatibility of RabbitMQ with the then newly released R15A version of erlang. Switching back to R14B3 solved the problem for me.